# Java элементы дерева JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Разобрал стандартные примеры с JTree. Собственно возник вопрос, возможно ли заменить элементы JTree на другой компонент, что бы при разворачивании, допустим, появлялись несколько JPanel. Пример на ниже на изображении. Если это нельзя сделать с JTree то через что это можно сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете полностью изменить отображение узлов дерева используя [setCellRenderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#setCellRenderer-javax.swing.tree.TreeCellRenderer-). По умолчанию там используется `JLabel`, но вы можете заметить эту компоненту на вашу.